# SQL Server Timeouts - retries or longer timeouts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance

I have an UPDATE command that is failing due to a timeout on SQL Server. It's a large table used for storing events, and the primary key is a NON-clustered index (shouldn't really matter anyway as it's a uniqueidentifier column).

It's updating a single row: `update [table] set [field] = 1 where [primary_key] = [primary_key_value];`. The problem is likely to be that there are over 200,000,000 rows so it takes a long time to find each one.

In terms of SQL Server's preference, am I better off increasing the command timeout (yes, I know the default of 30 seconds is already 30 times longer than any reasonable query should take), or should I introduce maybe a *shorter* timeout, but retry over and over again (to a limit)?

So is one long 60 second command timeout better than 6 retries with 5 second timeouts?

In practice there'd be some sort of exponential backoff and circuit breaker implementation, of course.

Comment: Consider identifying the root cause of the timeout. Perhaps the `UPDATE` is touching more rows than necessary and in need of query/index tuning.

Comment: Good points. I've updated the question.

Comment: The singleton update should take no more than milliseconds if the PK index is being used as expected and there's no long-term blocking. Check the execution plan to verify the index is used as expected.

Comment: Can anyone think why this question was voted to be closed? I can't fix it if I don't know why.

Comment: The voter voted to close as "primarily opinion based". I guess that's because you asked whether one long timeout is better than a shorter timeout with retries.

Comment: How is this opinion based? I wanted answers from someone who literally knew which was the correct approach, given how sql server actually works. Oh well. I should know to expect this from stackoverflow by now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Retrying is only going to help if the reason for the timeout is due to resource contention.  In that case, you are probably better off with some sort of exponential backoff, rather than just running the queries immediately.

However, I would speculate that the reason is due to either:

- An unoptimized query.
- A large number of rows being updated.

If the number of rows is the issue, you can limit the `update` to, say, 100 rows and repeat the update until all are completed.  However, I would first investigate the query to see if it can be can be optimized in other ways.

Comment: It's a single row. `update [table] set [field] = 1 where [primary_key] = [primary_key_value];`. The problem is likely to be that there are over 200,000,000 rows so it takes a long time to find each one. Good point about the backing-off. I should've mentioned that backing off and a circuit breaker was likely to be the actual solution I went with. I was just trying to find out whether retries are better than longer timeouts in general.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell . . . It takes basically no time to find a single row if you are using a primary key index.  Okay, it does take some time.  And loading the index could take time.  But unless you are in a severely memory limited environment, the primary key index is probably already completely in memory.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell . . . From a systems perspective, I think the best approach is multiple shorter timeouts.  This gets the load off the system and can free resources, clearing out bottlenecks.  This is a general principle, not just for databases.